# How to click on the Log In button in https://phptravels.com/demo/

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio Selenium C#.  URL:  https://phptravels.com/demo/.  Selenium C# Chromedriver

Inspect Element: Log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a hyperlink disguised as a button. Just redirect to: https://phptravels.org/ and you should be all set.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://phptravels.org/");
```

Comment: Thanks but I Inspect the Login button and seems not be able to use the correct method.  I have been using the XPath, CSSelector, Linktext and it is not working when executing my script

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying, so I don't need to worry about clicking on it?  Thanks